# Differential Equation: Sinusoidal Identity problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, real-numbers

Find a solution of $y' −\sqrt3y = \sin t + \cos t$

1) $(A,B) = (1,1)$, $w=1$

$R\cos(wt-\phi) = \sqrt2cos(t-\frac{\pi}{4})$

2)$M=(aA+Bw)/(w^2 + a^2)= (\sqrt3 +1)/4$

$N=(wA-Ba)/(w^2 + a^2)= \frac{1-\sqrt3}4$

3) $y'=ay + M \cos t + N \sin t = \sqrt3y + ((\sqrt3 +1)/4)* \cos t + \frac{1-\sqrt 3}4) \sin t$

**Is my solution right or wrong? Thanks**

Comment: It is wrong in the sense that it does not solve the equation. (Not counting the fact that it is pretty hard to follow by lack of explanations.)

Answer (score 1):

By educated guess, we can try a particular solution which is a sinusoid of the same frequency as the RHS,

$$y=A\cos t+B\sin t.$$

Plugging in the equation, we have

$$-A\sin t+B\cos t-\sqrt3A\cos t-\sqrt 3B\sin t=\sin t+\cos t.$$

Then by identification,

$$\begin{cases}\begin{align}-A-\sqrt3B&=1,\\B-\sqrt 3A&=1\end{align}\end{cases}$$ which is trivial to solve.

You need to add the general solution solution of the homogeneous equation

$$y'-\sqrt3y=0$$ giving 
$$\frac{y'}y=\sqrt3,\\
\log y=\sqrt3 t+C,\\
y=Ce^{\sqrt3 t}.$$